# Return row(i) if two columns match

Tags: r

I have two datasets:

df1

```
ID        paddock    cow ID
90/123    10         09/123
90/124    11         09/124
90/125    11         09/124
```

df2

```
ID        paddock
09/123    20
09/124    21
```

I would like to match df1$cowID with df2$ID and return df2$paddock for whatever row matches. My current code is as follows:

```
dt <- ifelse(df1$cowID %in% df2$ID, df2$paddock[i], NA)
```

But I'm getting a return error. Could someone direct me in the right direction please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have an error, it is typically better to include the actual error so we can help with it. Especially since we don't know what `i` is defined as (and I suspect it is wrong), we can only guess.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider joining the datasets.

```
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = c('cow ID', 'ID')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `match` :

```
df1$df2_paddock <- df2$paddock[match(df1$cow_ID, df2$ID)]
df1

#      ID paddock cow_ID df2_paddock
#1 90/123      10 09/123          20
#2 90/124      11 09/124          21
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:2, .Label = c("90/123", "90/124"
), class = "factor"), paddock = 10:11, cow_ID = structure(1:2, .Label = c("09/123", 
"09/124"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:2, .Label = c("09/123", "09/124"
), class = "factor"), paddock = 20:21), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by joining the two dataframes and getting the column that you want.

### Using Base R

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c("90/123", "90/124"),
    paddock = c(10, 11),
    cow_ID = c("09/123", "09/124")
  )

df2 <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c("90/123", "90/124"),
    paddock = c(20, 21)
  )

# Joining the two dataframes by ID then choosing column of interest
merge(df1, df2, by = c("ID"), suffixes = c(".x", ".y"))["paddock.y"]

# paddock.y
# 20
# 21
```

### Using Dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c("90/123", "90/124"),
    paddock = c(10, 11),
    cow_ID = c("09/123", "09/124")
  )

df2 <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c("90/123", "90/124"),
    paddock = c(20, 21)
  )

# Joining the two dataframes by ID then choosing column of interest
df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = c("ID"), suffixes = c(".x", ".y")) %>%
  select(paddock.y) %>%
  rename(paddock = paddock.y)

# paddock
# 20
# 21
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `ifelse()`, maybe you can use the following code to make it

```
with(df2,ifelse(ID %in% df1$cow_ID,paddock,NA))
```

such that

```
> with(df2,ifelse(ID %in% df1$cow_ID,paddock,NA))
[1] 20 21
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("90/123", "90/124", 
"90/125"), class = "factor"), paddock = c(10, 11, 11), cow_ID = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("09/123", "09/124"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:2, .Label = c("09/123", "09/124"
), class = "factor"), paddock = c(20, 21)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```